# React Link does not redirect properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using Link in react to redirect to an external link as follows:

```
<div className="btn-footer-padd">
    <Link className="career-btn sourceSansPro-sanSerif"
        target="_blank" 
        to="https://google.com"
    >Careers</Link>
</div>
```

Now when I try it it redirects like this:

```
http://myweburl/http://https://google.com
```

what I want is redirection to this:

```
http://https://google.com
```

Any idea?

Comment: Router is only for your in-app navigation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `<Link>` only with Router to let user navigate in your App.
If you want to redirect a user to an external url, use the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 3):

If you want to navigate away from your App, you should use a regular `<a>` React element.
If you wish to redirect user to some other route inside your App, you can use `<Redirect to="" />` component from 'react-router-dom'.